# How to find web apps that are 'alternatives to x'?

Tags: webapp-rec

**Ideally, this would help when you are looking for a new app and want to check out all the possible solutions, and also when you are looking to switch from your current app.**

Many of the questions on this site ask for 'alternatives to x' so hopefully this question can provide some information to help out these users.

Comment: Close Voters: This is meant to be a canonical "how to find alternative to X" question. The idea is that other questions asking for an alternative to a specific app can be closed as a duplicate of this. (Note that it's Community Wiki as well.) It should remain open.

Answer (score 16):

**AlternativeTo**

> AlternativeTo is a new approach to finding good software. Tell us what application you want to replace and we give you great alternatives, based on user recommendations.

http://alternativeto.net/desktop/dropbox/

Answer (score 14):

Google & Google suggest.

If you're looking for an alternative to Application X, just Google the phrases:
"Application X vs" and "vs Application X"

e.g. Dropbox.
Googling "Dropbox vs" and "vs dropbox" shows the following alternatives on page 1:
SugarSync, Mozy, Wuala, Drop.io, ZumoDrive, box.net, JungleDisk, Live Mesh, Syncplicity.

Google suggest is even better because it instantly shows the items people are currently comparing.

Just type "Dropbox vs " into the google.com search box, and wait for the suggestions to appear.

Suggest gives the following "crowdsourced" suggestions for "dropbox vs":
sugarsync, mobileme, idisk, box.net, mozy, google docs, evernote, live mesh, zumodrive.

Answer (score 9):

**Wikipedia**: if there is a page for one of the apps you are looking at, check to see if there is a 'category page' for that app type

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_notetaking_software

Answer (score 3):

**Xmarks Similar Sites**: enter in the url for a web app and then click to categories or look at the similar sites

http://www.xmarks.com/site/webapps.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

http://webapps.stackexchange.com ;)

Comment: Questions asking for recommendations are explicitly off-topic here, so this answer is not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

[What To Use](http://whattouse.com) is a service that helps you to find software based on specific tasks, topics and through users with similar interests.

Answer (score 0):

[**Hivefive**](http://lifehacker.com/tag/hivefive/) `Compares top 5` services/products in given domain. Very useful posts from `Lifehacker`

Answer (score 0):

If the app has been listed on [MakeUseOf](http://makeuseof.com) there is a long list of similar apps on their listings.  I have found this to be quite useful..

Answer (score 0):

http://www.softwaresuggest.com/ lists software in different categories and is community supported

Answer (score -1):

I found asking on Quora directly was the best. There's plenty of alternative to type of questions on Quora that doesn't get closed because of strict guidelines.